# Random Cells From A List In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sample[image]

Code:

```
=ArrayFormula((VLOOKUP(QUERY(UNIQUE(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A)*10))^0;COUNTA(A:A)));"limit 4");{ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A)));FILTER(A:A;A:A<>"")};2;0)))
```

I'm trying  but got this error,

[image: test1]
test 1

Can anyone tell what's wrong? To make my code
to work as in the first picture

error in #REF!
VLOOKUP evaluates outside the range bounds.

im try change code

```
=ArrayFormula((VLOOKUP(QUERY(UNIQUE(RANDBETWEEN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A)*10))^0,COUNTA(A:A))),"limit 4"),{ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A)));FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")},1,0)))
```

but number

[image]

solution for that?

Comment: What is the error description? (pass the mointer over the red triangle). Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: VLOOKUP evaluates outside the range bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FLOOR(RANDARRAY(5)*COUNTA(A2:A)),{SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A),1,0),A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))},2))
```

- Create `5` random integers using `RANDARRAY` between `0`(inclusive) and  number of entries in `A2:A`(i.e., `COUNTA`)(exclusive).
- Create a artificial side by side array(`{arr1,arr2}`) of `SEQUENCE` of numbers (from `0`) and actual values in `A2:A`
- `VLOOKUP` the random integers in the created artificial array to give random  values in `A:A`

If you're in locales that [use comma as decimal separators, The artificial array should be created using `\`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) instead of `,`(`{arr1\arr2}`).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FLOOR(RANDARRAY(5)*COUNTA(A2:A));{SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A);1;0)\A2:INDEX(A2:A;COUNTA(A2:A))};2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

On the first formula

```
{ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A)));FILTER(A:A;A:A<>"")}
```

replace the semicolon `;` between `INDIRECT()` and `FILTER()` by a backslash `\`  as using a semicolon appends the results of FILTER to the results of INDIRECT but you are looking to put the results of each function on their own column. Please note that this formula is using semicolons as argument separator.

On the second formula replace the semicolon `;` between `INDIRECT()` and `FILTER()` by a comma `,`  (and replace the third argument of `VLOOKUP`, 1, by 2. Please note that this formula is using commas as argument separators.

Explanation

- Commas are used as argument separator on spreadsheets that use dot as decimal separator (`=SUM(1,2,3)`) but also use commas as columns separator on arrays (`{"a","b"}`)
- Semicolons are used as argument separator on spreadsheets that use comma as decimal separator (`=SUM(1;2;3)`). On these spreadsheets, backslashes are used as columns separator on arrays (`{"a"\"b"}`);

References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: I think you interchanged. Semicolons are put as is. Commas are the ones changed to \

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. I changed a bit the wording.

Comment: @IndraRoyalSilver I think that you meand that you accepted the other answer because it includes a complete formula. That is fine.

Comment: @TheMaster The first part of my answer is about the changes that should be done to the OP formulas :)

Comment: Ok I finally got it :) Sorry. Need coffee

Comment: @TheMaster No problem. Sometimes I apply brevity to the extremes :D